# How to get the documentation reference pages for all commands that are ending with "Form"?

Tags: documentation, reference-request

Is there a way to get the documentation reference pages for all commands that are ending with "Form"?

Comment: You can use `?*Form`

Comment: @ulvi Thank you. Solved.